# Firing custom events / General event handling

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I'm getting into event handling now, and it seems quite confusing to me. See, I come from a web-dev background, so this event stuff is quite new to me.

I'm developing in C# / VS08 and created my Application in the WinForm-Designer.

Now, I created this program overview;

```
ProgramContext
 MainForm : Form
 LoginForm : Form
```

So, what I want to do is when the user clicks "Logout" (What is a menu item in the MainMenu of MainForm), that the application logs out the user.

But how can I access the "Click" event of the logout item from the ProgramContext's view, as there is all the logic of logging in etc.

I tried the following

```
MenuItem[] findLogout = MainMenuStrip.Items.Find("logoutMenuItem", true); // Throws NullPointerException
findLogout[0].Click += new EventHandler(LogoutClick);

private void LogoutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Logout user
}
```

But keep getting a NullPointerException at the first line.

Comment: so where exactly so you get the exception?

Comment: The first line of the example `MenuItem[] findLogout ...`

Comment: Can you verify that MainMenuStrip is not null at the point of calling and that MainMenuString.Items is not null at the point of calling and that findLogout is not an empty array?  Without context these seem to be the weakest points in the code for NULL references.

Comment: Well, I create the `MainForm` object befor the code above of course, and therefore all the controls of the Form are loaded, aren't they?

Comment: Where in the form code is this being done?  I usually do this sort of thing in the Load event handler of the form -- because then I can be sure that everything is instantiated and configured. I guess it's possible that the MainMenuStrip is created but hasn't has it's Items array filled yet?

Comment: If you know the index of the item you want to find, you can simply do MainMenuStrip.Items[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to expose an event on MainForm:

```
public EventHandler LogOut;
```

Then hook into this from your `ProgramContext`:

```
MainForm form = new MainForm();
form.LogOut += new EventHandler(MainForm_LogOut);

void MainForm_LogOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logout
}
```

Then fire the LogOut button is pressed on the MainMenu using the following code in the Menu Item's click event:

```
private void LogoutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LogOut != null)
    {
        LogOut(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ApoY2k - This is the practice I use personally. Say, for example, you add another log out button to your MainForm, or you add a timeout which causes a log out. Wouldn't you want that to be communicated back to the Program Context as well? Using your current method you'd need to capture an event per object that causes a log out. With my example, you just call `LogOut(sender, e);` at any pont where you want to do a logout.